# erc20 claim token transfer function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, erc20, openzeppelin

I have this contract and trying to call the claimFreeToken function. Contract already doesn't have enough tokens but the function doesn't return an error and also token doesn't receive. Where did I overlook it?

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract TestToken is ERC20 {
    constructor(uint256 initialSupply) ERC20("Test Token", "TET") {
        _mint(msg.sender, initialSupply * (10**decimals()));
    }

    function claimFreeToken() public payable {
        transfer(msg.sender, 1000 * (10**decimals()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your implementation makes token transferred from your wallet to your wallet on claiming, not from the contract.

The `transfer` function in ERC20 will send from the `msg.sender` to the specified address. So, in this case you are transferring from `msg.sender` to `msg.sender`.

The correct implementation should be like this,

```
function claimFreeToken() public payable {
    _transfer(address(this), msg.sender, 1000 * (10**decimals()));
}
```

Read more: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol#L113